# Trying to prevent multiple rapid button presses, but the buttons aren't disabling properly

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a situation where I am trying to prevent the user from spamming a button, and to do this I have my command taking two functions as parameters. The first is the command that figures out which button was pressed and then performs the appropriate navigation operation. As it stands now when you press the button there is a short delay, I assume while data is loaded, and then the buttons disable a millisecond before the new page is loaded and presented. I would like them to disable as soon as a button press has occurred so they can't be spammed and load multiple pages of the same type.

This specific button press I am trying to resolve has the Page1 ViewModel retrieving an SQL table from a web service. The call to this is in the Page1ViewModel's constructor.

```
    NavigateAsyncCommand = new RelayCommandAsync<object>(NavigateAsync, CanClickButton);

    public async Task NavigateAsync(object parameter)
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        Xamarin.Forms.Button b = parameter as Xamarin.Forms.Button;
        string page = b.Text;

        switch (page)
        {
            case "Page1":
                await App.MainNavigation.PushAsync(new Views.Page1(), true);
                IsBusy = false;
                return;

            //More cases here
        }
    }
```

The second function just checks the status of IsBusy and returns the inverse.

```
    public bool CanClickButton(object parameter)
    {
        return !IsBusy;
    }
```

In my XAML my buttons are implemented like this

```
        <Button x:Name="StartButton" 
             Command="{Binding NavigateAsyncCommand}" 
             CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference StartButton}}"
             Text="{Binding StartText}"
             Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Comment: I dont think the solution there is relevant to me, as my application isn't using custom animations or anything like that. The delay comes from the application fetching a SQL table from a web service, so the delay will be variable depending on network speed.

Comment: Try adding `NavigateAsyncCommand.OnCanExecuteChanged()` after changing `IsBusy` value to `true` in `NavigateAsync` method. You need to inform the UI that a commands `CanExecute` has changed.

Comment: @foxanna Thank you for the suggestion but unfortunately that didn't work. The delay between pressing the button and it greying out is still there.

Comment: By the way, you don't have to pass the entire button into a command as a parameter if all you need is its text. Create binding like this: `CommandParameter="{Binding StartText}"` and read a parameter of `NavigateAsync` directly to `string page = (string) parameter`.

Comment: @foxanna I know. I originally had it that way, but I changed it to this to see if changing the `IsEnabled` property in the C# would work. It did not.

Comment: @foxanna Wait a minute, I've been a little slow. Your initial solution did partially work, but it just doesn't update the actual UI. It prevents spam clicking but the buttons still look like they're enabled.

Comment: As a workaround, you can create a child of a `Button` control that would disable itself for 500 ms each time it is clicked. I had this solution in the app for elderly people who have arms tremor and simply cannot perform a single tap on a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue once. The way I solved it was the following:

1) I created a "reverse boolean converter"

```
public class ReverseBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            bool myValue = (bool)value;
            return !myValue ; 
        }
        catch { return true; } // or false
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
    }
}
```

2) I referenced the converter into xaml header

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Converters"
```

3) I added the converter into a resource dictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary>
     <converters:ReverseBooleanConverter x:Key="ReverseBool" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

4) Last step, I binded `IsEnabled` to the `IsBusy` property of the viewmodel, using the above converter.

```
<Button x:Name="StartButton" 
    IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource ReverseBool}}" 
    ...
    Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the closest to your initial code solution:

```
    NavigateCommand = new RelayCommandAsync<object>(NavigateAsync, CanNavigate);  

    ...
    private async Task NavigateAsync(object parameter)
    {
        if (IsBusy)
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        IsBusy = true;
        NavigateCommand.OnCanExecuteChanged();

        var page = (string) parameter;

        switch (page)
        {
            case "Page1":
                await App.MainNavigation.PushAsync(new Views.Page1(), true);

            //More cases here
        }

        IsBusy = false;
        NavigateCommand.OnCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    private bool CanNavigate(object parameter) => !IsBusy;

    ...
    <Button Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding StartText}"
            Text="{Binding StartText}"
            Grid.Row="1"/>
```

It will inform Button that `CanExecute` has changed each time `IsBusy` value changes. And it will ignore clicks that pass through.

In general, you should not init any long-running operation in ViewModel `ctor` keeping it as simple as possible. Instead, use `Page.OnAppearing` to inform ViewModel it can start loading.